# "Control Break Processing" in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to replicate the old "[control break processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break)" in SSIS.
I want to group my records by a common value e.g.  Suburb.

So, sort the records by suburb and then read the records which belong to the first suburb and process those records. Then continue and collect the next group/suburb etc .

Easy enough in COBOL but can't figure out if the loops in SSIS or anything else can do the same.

[What is a control break? (COBOL)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15978750/181965)
here is the pseudo code for a control break process

Read first record

```
--Seed control key
@Suburbkey = rs(“Suburb”)

While Not rs.oef
    If rs(“Suburb”) <> @SuburbKey then
        --Process Batched records
                Process @BatchRS

        --Empty batched records
        @BatchRS = null
            End if

    @BatchRS.add = Rs

    @SuburbKey = rs(“Suburb”)
    rs.MoveNext
End while
```

Comment: So even reading the two links on control break, I still don't comprehend how to emulate Control Break Processing. I suspect that might not even be the correct paradigm for SSIS. Would you please click the Edit button and give an example of what the "process those records" would be. It may be that Ako's example is what you're looking for but it might just be that you're attempting to use vise grips to twist a socket when you really just need to grab a metric wrench

Comment: Every time a sentinel values changes, Do X. What is *X*? Depending on what you're doing, what Ako shows below could be correct. Or, it could be very much *not* the way to do something in a standard fashion for SSIS. For example, if you have sample set of data and every time the postal code changes, you want to go and determine the correct city and state for the entity. That would fit with your control break model, but would be more intuitively written as a lookup task within a Data Flow. You don't care about the specific processing, instead, you describe what should happen & let the tool work.

Comment: The actual logic within the control break process is a bit more complex. I'm actually doing an end of year financial rollover.  I need to group the records by the account and then look at values in the last record and the first record of that group to do calculations.  And then generate a new cored from those values.

Comment: So for suburb/account/X, you need to lookup the first and last values in fiscal year 2014. Is this basically going to generate two values StartBalance and EndBalance? If so, is there any reason you can just compute the start and end balance for all suburb/account/X in that system? Then you just run the accounts you care about against that set and there's your output? I'm sure this is clear as day in your head and so I apologize but to be able to help you, I really want to make sure we're both solving the same problem.

Comment: So, the goal is not breaking up the work to do, but doing something special on certain similar values. In that case would it work to solve in data flow component with a sort and scripting component (not script task) ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? Gather some work items, put in a System.Object variable and process them one by one in a for each (for) loop.

[image: Breaking up work in control flow]

Comment: No.  the For each loop would allow you to get one record at a time. and would be similar to the While Not rs.eof in my example.  However, the grouping of like records within the loop i.e. the control break,  I  can only see as being possible with a script task.  I'm just not sure if that is the best way to process it.