# PHP: Category and subcategories from the same table and row?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id            di_make              di_model

1             Samsung               TV656  
2             Samsung               TV555
3              Sony                 LCD33
```

I need to create a category and subcategories menu from this table...

LIKE THIS:

http://jsfiddle.net/7NYhe/500/

So i tried this:

```
$storecategories = "";
$storesubcategories = "";

$sql2="SELECT DISTINCT `di_make` FROM `products` ORDER BY id";
$query2 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql2);
$existCount2 = mysqli_num_rows($query2);
if ($existCount2!=0) {

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

$di_makeC = $row2["di_make"];


/////Create sub categories/////////
$sql3="SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE di_make='$di_makeC'";
$query3 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql3);
$existCount3 = mysqli_num_rows($query3);
if ($existCount3!=0) {

while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

$di_modelC = $row3["di_model"];

$storesubcategories .='<li>'.$di_modelC.'</li>';



}
}
/////End of Create sub categories/////////


 $storecategories .= '<li class="dropdown">'.$di_makeC.'
      <ul>
           '.$storesubcategories.'
      </ul>
   </li>';

}
}
```

However, the code above acts weirdly!

By that I mean, it will create the Categories and then create the subcategories BUT it will repeat the subcategories from the second category.

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/7NYhe/501/

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don’t do this by nesting queries in loops (that should be avoided generally, bad performance). Use one query, that selects the data ordered by di_make first, and then implement a simple _control break_ to create the necessary HTML structure.

Comment: @CBroe, Any chance you could provide an example of control break?

Comment: you can try `group by di_make` in a query.

Comment: Here you can find a general explanation of the principle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978750/what-is-a-control-break-cobol Basically you compare the value of the current “row” with that of the previous one, and based on whether they are the same or not, you decide what output needs to generated.

Comment: @shanechiu, group by produces the same result!